# How to change git pull strategy to merge by default

Tags: git, github

I cloned a new repo and while pulling for the first time I was asked to set the default merge strategy. I set it to rebase using `git config --global pull.rebase true`. Now I want to set it back to merge so I used `git config --global pull.rebase false` and  `git config --global pull.merge true` but still whenever I pull changes, it takes me to a rebase flow.

I think I'm using the right command but I'm not that well-versed in the different strategies that are there like ff.

Comment: I can’t seem to find the `pull.merge` option that you mention? On Git 2.40

Comment: Because it doesn't exist. User is just thrashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delete the mistakes by hand editing the gitconfig file. Or:

```
git config --global --unset pull.rebase
git config --global --unset pull.merge
git config --global pull.ff only
```

That will fix it.

But even better would be: never say `git pull`, for this very reason. Say `git fetch; git merge` like the pros do.

Comment: Thanks a lot @matt . I knew that the merge option didn't exist but since I couldn't find anything I tried that. Mentioned it here, thinking if it'd add an extra key in my config which might cause some other issues.